# Python Anonymous Object not Created?

Tags: python, list, object

This is working well -

```
mydict = {...some data...}
another = mydict.keys()
another.sort(key=sort_key, reverse=True)
for v in another:...
```

while this isn't -

```
for v in mydict.keys().sort(key=sort_key, reverse=True):...
```

throws

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Why?

Comment: Don't call things `list` or `dict`, it overwrites the builtin function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) will return you `None`.

Variable `list` is dict in your example 
Means `list.keys()` is `list` data type and `list.sort` will give sorted `list` itself. But return None

```
>>> list = {1:1, 2:2}
>>> list.keys()
[1, 2]
>>> list.keys().sort()
>>> b = list.keys().sort()
>>> b
>>> print b
None
```

When you try to iterate over none

```
>>> [x for x in list.keys().sort()]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

It gives error